# How to avoid re-downloading country borders from Wikipedia's SVG pictures each time?

Tags: wikipedia

There are a lot of political maps on Wikipedia where each country is coloured depending of various things. On preview smaller countries are not visible.

SVG source is usually big, as it contains borders between all countries.

But when I view more than one such map, borders are usually the same and only colours differ.

How to avoid downloading almost the same map in SVG again and again and only download colouring and other essential details?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reasonable way to do that without some support from both the server and the client. And Wikipedia treats each SVG as a separate file, so there is no way to download only the parts of one file that differ from another file.

The only way I can think of to do this would be to try to *guess* which part of the two files is going to be different and download only that. But writing a program that does that would be hard and it still probably wouldn't always work correctly. I certainly don't think it would be worth the few hundred megabytes of downloading that you would save this way.

Comment: I remember buying "100 MB of internet" cards. The missing component is probably multi-file SVGs with dependencies.